# What Terraria content is unique to IOS?

Tags: terraria-mobile

What items, gear, or other content is only available on the IOS version of Terraria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the exclusive mobile content is as follows. ([Source](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Mobile_version))

**Armour**

[image: Boots of Ostara][Boots of Ostara](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Boots_of_Ostara)

**Weapons**

[image][Egg Cannon](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Egg_Cannon)

**Explosives**

[image] [Holy Hand Grenade](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Holy_Hand_Grenade)

**Enemies**

[Diseaster Bunny](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Diseaster_Bunny)

**Boss**

[image][Lepus](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Lepus)

**Events**

[image][Easter](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Easter)

**Pets**

Too many to list, see [here](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Mobile_version)

**Items**

Too many to list, see [here](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Mobile_version)

**Have fun!**

Comment: Thanks Caleb! Is Easter the only special event Terraria has done on IOS with unique content?

Comment: We must use the Holy Hand Grenade!

Comment: At least one of the listed things is both console and ios, are you sure that all of the rest are ios only?

Comment: I have not come across any of the above on the Xbox 360, and going by the wiki all of the above is in fact mobile exclusive, though I haven't seen all of them before.

Comment: @Caleb Read the wiki for dragon armor at least. Notice it says 'mobile/console exclusive'. Thus, it is not exclusive to just mobile, since it is also on console. I know for a fact that the wiki is correct, it is on the console.

Comment: @Caleb Yeah, there's a number of these that aren't just on mobile, and are on pc as well. If the wiki article says "Console/Mobile-Only Content:" at the top as opposed to "Mobile-Only Content", it is not mobile exclusive.

Comment: @Caleb Really not sure why you reverted my edit, considering it made it correct.

Comment: Dat scary rabbit tho...

Comment: @Waterseas It looked like you were defacing the post.

Comment: @Caleb I was not, I was correcting it.

Comment: @Waterseas Doesn't matter anymore, sorry.